# Keeping things safe from the darkest grasps

Tags: riddle

> I am wet and cold,
> Yet I am strong and bold.
> Poison to those against me,
> I slide along, keeping things safe from the darkest grasps. 
> Leaving a trail of death behind, I let you live in peace.

#### What am I?

**Hint**

> It is an everyday household object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> an anti-bacterial wipe?

I am wet and cold.

> Wipes are wet and cold.

Yet I am strong and bold.

> Wipes are fairly resilient.

Poison to those against me.

> The anti-bacterial properties kill harmful bacteria.

Sliding along, while keeping things safe from the darkest grasps.

> "Sliding" describes the action of somebody using a wipe to clean a work surface, for example.

Leaving a trail of death behind, I let you live in peace.

> Harmful bacteria is killed when passed over by the anti-bacterial wipe.

Answer (score 2):

> You could be describing **pesticides** in farming, or insecticides in the house?
>
>  Or **antibiotics** that save us from the darkest grasps of disease ?

Comment: You are close! :)